# Input and submit button in the same line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I use a plugin in Wordpress (Sendpress) and I try to make a few changes in the form. The html code is this one:

```
  <form class="sendpress-signup" method="post" id="sendpress_signup">
    <div id="form-wrap">
      <input type="hidden" value="1688" class="sp_list" id="list" name="sp_list" />

      <p name="email"><label for="email">Newsletter - Stay Tuned:</label> <input type=
      "text" name="sp_email" value="" orig="Newsletter - Stay Tuned" class=
      "sp_email" /></p>

      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class=
      "sendpress-submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </div>
```

Here is a jsFiddle of what I have done until now [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTLJA/1546/)

What I want to do is to put the submit button next to input field without a space between them. Is there any way to do this only with CSS? I prefer to now change the code of plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FTLJA/1549/)**

HTML:

```
 <p name="email">
            <label for="email">Newsletter - Stay Tuned:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sp_email" value="" orig="Newsletter - Stay Tuned" class="sp_email" />
             <span class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="sendpress-submit" value="Submit" />
        </span>
        </p>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    border: 3px solid #be2e26;
    padding: 5px;
}
.sendpress-submit {
    margin: 0 0 0 -7px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #be2e26;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 5px;
   border: 3px solid #be2e26;
}
```

Comment: I will choose the answer as the correct in 5 minutes due to the time limit

Answer (score 2):

try this demo
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTLJA/1550/)

```
p[name="email"]{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: That will float **all** paragraphs to the left.